# Use Eloquent/Builder instance in other Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to use a Eloquent/Builder Instance in an other Eloquent Query?

For example, if I have this query:

```
$users = User::whereHas('posts', function($query) { $query->where('great_post', true); })->get();
```

Can I somehow split in two parts like this?

```
$postsQuery = Posts::where('great_post', true);
$users = User::where('posts', $postsQuery)->get(); // not working
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Get users with their great posts ? What does "posts" column look like ?

Comment: It's just a simple example, I just want to know if it's possible to take the closure out in a separate variable and use it in a other eloquent query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:

```
$postsQuery = function($query) { $query->where('great_post', true);};
$users = User::where('posts', $postsQuery)->get();
```

But there is other way called [Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes) in Laravel and I recomment you use it if this subquery can be reused again in other queries.
**For example:**

```
class User extends Model
{       
    public function scopeHasPosts($query)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('posts', function($subquery) { 
        $subquery->where('great_post', true); });
    }        
}
```

then call it like this: 
`$users = User::hasPosts()->get();`